# can´t decode special characters from gmail - python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, imap

I made a program which receives an email from a Gmail account and it saves its information, specifically the name's sender of the email, the subject and the body as plain text.

I get this information as strings, but the problem is that the decodification can´t recognise special characters like accents. I tried decoding the email's bytes content with UTF-8, iso-8859-1 and latin-1 but I can't decode correctly the special characters.

Here is the code that I have and some print example.

```
        result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')    
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]

        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('iso-8859-1')

        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

        cuerpomensaje = email_message.get_payload()[0]
        body = cuerpomensaje.get_payload()
        textoplano = None

        if type(body) == list:
            textoplano = body[0].get_payload()

        elif type(body) == str:
            textoplano = body

        emisor = email_message['From']

    print(email.utils.parseaddr(emisor)[0])
    print(email_message['Subject'])
    print(textoplano)
```

When printing, I obtain this:

`=?UTF-8?Q?Andr=C3=A9s?=
=?UTF-8?Q?=C3=A1rbol_de_la_tierra?=
palabras con tilde como =C3=A1rbol`

But I should get this:

`Andrés
árbol de la tierra
palabras con tilde como árbol`

Comment: You shouldn't decode your email string yourself, use message from bytes in py 3.6.    What sets emisor,  I don't see it being assigned.

Comment: I set email_message with email.message_from_bytes(raw_email), but still can't get the characters fixed

Comment: I've not used it myself, but you should look more carefully at the new Email APIs here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.parser.html#module-email.parser, specifically, setting a policy, which should cause it to parse the headers for you.  The old legacy library made this very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

import urllib.parse


def decode(text):
    if text.startswith('=?UTF-8?Q?') and text.endswith('?='):
        text = re.search('=\?UTF-8\?Q\?(.*)\?=', text).group(1)
    return urllib.parse.unquote(text.replace('=', '%'))
```

Result:

```
print(decode('=?UTF-8?Q?Andr=C3=A9s?='))
>>> Andrés

print(decode('=?UTF-8?Q?=C3=A1rbol_de_la_tierra?=').replace('_', ' '))
>>> árbol de la tierra

print(decode('palabras con tilde como =C3=A1rbol'))
>>> palabras con tilde como árbol
```

**You can also to use with package email.header**

```
from email.header import decode_header

s, d = decode_header('=?UTF-8?Q?=C3=A1rbol_de_la_tierra?=')[0]
print(s.decode(d))
```

Comment: This submits an error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: this code work on this specific case, but not for all strings. For example, when subject and textoplano is "árbol canción", the result of printing them is:

`%?UTF-8?B?w6FyYm9sIGNhbmNpw7Nu?%

w6FyYm9sIGNhbmNpw7NuDQo%`

Comment: Actually, when printing the email content as bytes on `raw_email`, the special characters aren't got correctly